# Minimizing the rate of geometric ergodicity of a Metropolis-Hastings kernel

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings, measure-theory, ergodic

Let $\kappa$ denote the transition kernel of the symmetric Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ and target distribution $\mu$.

> What would be a general guideline if we're aiming to show that (in a particular instance of the problem) $\kappa$ is geometric ergodic with a preferably small rate $\rho\in(0,1)$, i.e. $$\left\|\kappa^n(x,\;\cdot\;)-\mu\right\|\le M(x)\rho^n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag1,$$ where $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|$ denotes the total variation norm and $M(x)<\infty$, for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in E$?

Let $x\in E$. We know that $$\left\|\kappa(x,\;\cdot\;)-\mu\right\|=\frac12\sup_{\left\|f\right\|_\infty\le1}|(\kappa f)(x)-\mu f|\tag2.$$ Maybe we can do something like this: Let $A_x:=\left\{\alpha(x,\;\cdot\;)=1\right\}$ and $R_x:=A_x^c$. Now left $f:E\to\mathbb R$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $\left\|f\right\|_\infty\le1$. Then, \begin{equation}\begin{split}|(\kappa f)(x)-\mu f|&=\left|\int\lambda({\rm d}y)(k(x,y)-p(y))(f(y)-f(x))\right|\\&\le2\int\lambda({\rm d}y)|k(x,y)-p(y)|\end{split}\tag3\end{equation} and \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\int\lambda({\rm d}y)|k(x,y)-p(y)|\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;=\int_{A_x\:\cap\:\{\:p\:=\:0\:\}}\lambda({\rm d}y)q(x,y)+\int_{A_x\:\cap\:\{\:p\:>\:0\:\}}\mu({\rm d}y)\left|\frac{q(x,y)}{p(y)}-1\right|\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;+\int_{R_x}\mu({\rm d}y)\left|\frac{q(x,y)}{p(x)}-1\right|,\end{split}\tag4\end{equation} where $k(x,y):=q(x,y)\alpha(x,y)$ for $x,y\in E$.

> Maybe we can attempt to minimize $(4)$. Is this a feasible approach? My goal would be to apply this in the particular instance of my other question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/346120/91890.

*Definitions*: Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space;
- $p$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ and $\mu:=p\lambda$;
- $Q$ be a Markov kernel on $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $$Q(x,B)=\int_B\lambda({\rm d}y)q(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E\tag1$$ for some symmetric $\mathcal E^{\otimes2}$-measurable $q:E^2\to[0,\infty)$;
- $$\alpha(x,y):=\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle1\wedge\frac{p(y)}{p(x)}&\text{, if }p(x)>0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E;$$
- $$\tilde\kappa(x,B):=\int_BQ(x,{\rm d}y)\alpha(x,y)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$$ and $$\kappa(x,B):=\tilde\kappa(x,B)+\underbrace{\left(1-\tilde\kappa(x,B)\right)}_{=:\:r(x)}1_B(x)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$$